# Multiselect with WPF and MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Implementing my viewModel to provide the code for a single select using a `ComboBox` in my view is quite easy:

```
public class TransportViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private Transport _primaryModel;
    private ObservableCollection<Remark> _cargoRemarks;

    public ObservableCollection<Remark> CargoRemarks
    {
        get { return _cargoRemarks; }
        set
        {
            if (_cargoRemarks != value)
            {
                _cargoRemarks = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CargoRemarks");
            }
        }
    }
    public Remark SelectedCargoRemark
    {
        get { return _primaryModel.CargoRemark; }
        set
        {
            if (_primaryModel.CargoRemark != value)
            {
                _primaryModel.CargoRemark = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCargoRemark");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The view can now use it like that:

```
<ComboBox ... ItemsSource="{Binding CargoRemarks, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCargoRemark, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

However I wonder what I have to change in my view and viewModel to provide a multi select (not only one remark, but 1-n remarks can be selected).

This has been discussed a couple of times but those discussions are mostly over 4 years old, look very complicated, require additional frameworks or classes. Is there any "slim" solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](http://our.componentone.com/2013/09/26/multiselect-combobox-mvvm-way/). This may be useful to you.

Comment: This is for an external library/product. So not really what I'm looking for.